# How can I send mass email to all contribution page pcp owners?

Tags: email, contributions, pcp

I have a contribution page that has pcp enabled. I want to send out a mass email to all the pcp owners. I can display a list of all the pages with owners, but I can't do any actions on them. Is there an easy (or even a hard) way to do this?

Comment: I think PCP stands for "Personal Campaign Page".

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a blind spot in CiviCRM!  I don't think there's anything except a very hard way:  Write SQL to get the contact IDs, then import those IDs, assigning them to a new group.

To get the IDs of EVERYONE with a PCP, here's the SQL:

`SELECT contact_id from civicrm_pcp;`

If you want to get the PCPs associated with a particular contribution page, and that contribution page's ID is 12, here's the SQL:

`SELECT contact_id from civicrm_pcp cp JOIN civicrm_pcp_block cpb on cp.pcp_block_id = cpb.id WHERE cpb.entity_id = 12 AND cpb.entity_table = 'contribute';`

If it's an event page, change `contribute` to `event`.

Export that as CSV (this is trivial in PHPMyAdmin, for command line you can look up syntax).  Import the list of ONLY contact IDs to CiviCRM through **Contacts menu » Import Contacts**. On screen 4 of 4 of the import, you can specify a (new or existing) group to add your contacts to.  Once it's imported, you can mass mail the contacts.

Sorry it's such a hassle!  Hopefully an organization invested in PCPs will step up and fund a better solution.  If nothing else, a custom search would be easy to write.